# ros::InvalidNameException error

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I am trying to create an executable node called "motor_driver_node" in a package called "motor_driver". The purpose of this node is to run a C++ file called "ego_points.cpp". The node was created when I compiled my workspace with "catkin_make" however when I attempt to run the node, I get the following error:

```
student@MENG2321103LT02:~/Desktop/Naes_Thesis/src$ rosrun motor_driver motor_driver_node 
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'ros::InvalidNameException'
what():  Character [.] at element [10] is not valid in Graph Resource Name [ego_points.cpp].  Valid characters are a-z, A-Z, 
0-9, / and _.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Here is my CMakeLists.txt file for the motor_driver_package:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(motor_driver)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  rplidar_ros
  roscpp
  serial
  std_msgs
  sensor_msgs
  message_generation
 )

find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS system)

add_message_files(FILES
  Motor_speeds.msg
  cartesian.msg
)

generate_messages(DEPENDENCIES
  std_msgs
  sensor_msgs
  motor_driver
)

catkin_package(
  CATKIN_DEPENDS rospy roscpp serial std_msgs message_runtime rplidar_ros sensor_msgs
)
   
${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS})

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}_node src/ego_points.cpp)

add_dependencies(${PROJECT_NAME}_node ${${PROJECT_NAME}_EXPORTED_TARGETS} 
   ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS})

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}_node
   ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
   )
```

Here is my Package.XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package>
  <name>motor_driver</name>
  <version>0.0.0</version>
  <description>The motor_driver package</description>
  
  <buildtool_depend>catkin</buildtool_depend>
  <build_depend>roscpp</build_depend>
  <build_depend>rospy</build_depend>
  <build_depend>serial</build_depend>
  <build_depend>std_msgs</build_depend>
  <build_depend>message_generation</build_depend>
  <build_depend>rplidar_ros</build_depend>
  <build_depend>sensor_msgs</build_depend>
  <run_depend>sensor_msgs</run_depend>
  <run_depend>rospy</run_depend>
  <run_depend>roscpp</run_depend>
  <run_depend>message_runtime</run_depend>
  <run_depend>serial</run_depend>
  <run_depend>rplidar_ros</run_depend>
  <run_depend>std_msgs</run_depend>
</package>
```

I assume that this error doesn't have anything to do with the ego_points.cpp file itself but I am putting it here anyways:

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include "sensor_msgs/LaserScan.h"
#include "iostream"
using namespace std;

void ScanCallback(const sensor_msgs::LaserScan::ConstPtr& scan) {
        int test = scan->ranges[1];
        cout << test << endl;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
        ros::init(argc, argv, "ego_points.cpp"); //This is always the first thing that has to happen. Allows it to use ROS.

        ros::NodeHandle nh; //First NodeHandle constructed will fully initialize this node.
        ros::Subscriber scanSub;
        scanSub = nh.subscribe<sensor_msgs::LaserScan>("/Scan",10, &ScanCallback);
        ros::spin();
        return 0;
}
```

Can someone please let me know what I am doing wrong? Thank you in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/262331/ros::invalidnameexception-error/) by [tylernaes](https://answers.ros.org/users/30489/tylernaes/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2017-05-22

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your error is saying that `ego_points.cpp` is not a valid name (for example a Node name or Topic name).

In your file, when you call ros::init you try to set the node's name to `ego_points.cpp`, but this isn't a valid name:

```
 ros::init(argc, argv, "ego_points.cpp");
```

Maybe you can just use `ego_points` as the node name instead:

```
ros::init(argc, argv, "ego_points");
```

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2017-05-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tylernaes](https://answers.ros.org/users/30489/tylernaes/) on 2017-05-23**:
Thank you so much. That was the issue. It works now.